# Can QGIS give GeoJSON layers a meaningful default name?

Tags: qgis, geojson

When I add a GeoJSON layer to my QGIS project, it always gets the name `OGRGeoJSON`. This is in contrast with shapefile layers, which seem to be named after the file name by default.

Is there a way to either configure QGIS or change my GeoJSON files so that they get a meaningful default name when I first add them to a project?

Comment: I think that may be configuration is somewhere in the actual geojson hash...thats just a guess I'm not sure. At least I hope it is...good question...too good...any luck on your end in the last 10 months?

Answer (score 1):

The issue was fixed in time for QGIS 2.6 http://hub.qgis.org/issues/10711#change-57013

Answer (score 0):

Use QGIS browser to add the GeoJSON file and it should work.